# Firestore recycler adapter - disappearing items after scrolling

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create chatting service for my project, in order to do that I store my messages in a Firestore database that I fetch from the server and assign the text comparing the sender id to current user id. 
When I start the activity, the messages show properly, but when I scroll down, either my messages stop showing up, or other user's messages disappear, depending whether on which account the chat is opened.

I can't seem to figure out why that happens.

My readMessages function:

```
private void readMessages(){
    Query query = DataRef.collection("rooms").document(roomID).collection("messages").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MessageModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<MessageModel>().setQuery(query, MessageModel.class).build();
    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<MessageModel, MessageAdapter.ViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position, MessageModel model) {
            if (myUid.equals(model.getUid())) {
                Log.d(TAG, "status1");
                holder.msg_right.setText(String.valueOf(model.getMsg()));
                holder.msg_left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.profile_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.msg_nick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                DataRef.collection("users").document(String.valueOf(model.getUid())).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        msgNick = document.getString("usernm");
                    }
                });
                holder.msg_nick.setText(msgNick);
                holder.msg_left.setText(String.valueOf(model.getMsg()));
                holder.msg_right.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(TAG, "status0" );
        }
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message,parent,false);
            return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
        }
    };
    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My message adapter class:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView msg_right;
        public ImageView profile_image;
        public TextView msg_left;
        public TextView msg_nick;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            msg_right = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg_right);
            profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg_leftavatar);
            msg_left = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg_left);
            msg_nick = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg_nick);
        }
    }
}
```

State of the chat before scrolling down and up:

"[image: State of the chat before scrolling down and up]

And after doing so:

[image: And after doing so]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Items not displaying in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763838/items-not-displaying-in-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to move the blow block of code of setting the `holder` members within the callback listener in `else` statement.

```
private void readMessages(){
    Query query = DataRef.collection("rooms").document(roomID).collection("messages").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MessageModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<MessageModel>().setQuery(query, MessageModel.class).build();
    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<MessageModel, MessageAdapter.ViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position, MessageModel model) {
            if (myUid.equals(model.getUid())) {
                Log.d(TAG, "status1");
                holder.msg_right.setText(String.valueOf(model.getMsg()));
                holder.msg_left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.profile_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.msg_nick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                DataRef.collection("users").document(String.valueOf(model.getUid())).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        msgNick = document.getString("usernm");
                        holder.msg_nick.setText(msgNick);
                        holder.msg_left.setText(String.valueOf(model.getMsg()));
                        holder.msg_right.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Log.d(TAG, "status0" );                    }
                });

        }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue still persists.